# knockout.chart.js: How to get instance id of the chart

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, charts

I've been trying to get knockout to work with chart.js (http://www.chartjs.org/). I found knockout.chart (https://github.com/grofit/knockout.chart) that someone has been kind enough to share. I'm trying to attach a click event to a segment on the chart, it seems like I have to use the chart.js prototype method .getSegmentsAtEvent(event) which uses the instance of the chart. My problem is that I don't know how to access the instance name of my chart since its created in the knockout.chart.js file.

This is how Chart.js suggest we use it in their documentation:

```
canvas.onclick = function(evt){
var activePoints = myDoughnutChart.getSegmentsAtEvent(evt);
// => activePoints is an array of segments on the canvas that are at the same position as the click event.
 };
```

I can't seem to trigger a click event on the canvas, so I've been trying to use the container div "ifWP".
Here is the section in the knockout.chart.js file where the chart is created:

```
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
  var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
  var chartBinding = allBindings.chart;
  var activeChart;
  var elementWidth = element.width;
  var elementHeight = element.height;

 var createChart = function() {
   var chartType = ko.unwrap(chartBinding.type);
   var context2d = element.getContext("2d");
   var data = ko.toJS(chartBinding.data);
   var options = ko.toJS(chartBinding.options)
   convertAllDataToNumeric(data); // ko treats values from inputs as strings, chart no likey
         activeChart = new Chart(context2d)[chartType](data, options);
   };
```

This is my html:

```
<div id="ifWP" data-bind="if: isWP">
    <canvas id="WPChart" width="300" height="300" data-bind="chart: { 
        type: 'Doughnut', 
        data: testArray, 
        options: { observeChanges: true, throttle: 100 } }">
    </canvas>
 </div>
```

And this is where I want to access details of a segment of the chart in my js file:

```
$("#ifWP").click(function (evt) {
var activePoints = self.activeChart.getSegmentsAtEvent(evt);
self.method(activePoints[0].label);
}
```

I'm probably overlooking something small. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you can keep everything in a working fiddle that would be great ..!

Comment: Seems like you'll need to modify knockout.chart.js. In the bindingHandler (init section), have it accept a parameter and where it creates the activeChart variable, assign that to the parameter.